# Having difficulties creating a "stand alone" compiler

Tags: c, linux, compiler-construction, programming-languages

Now before i start asking dumb questions,i'd like to say that i have a big experience in both JavaScript and C#.
So recently i went to the journey of creating my own porgramming language.
I found a good tutorial that uses javaScript
(http://lisperator.net/pltut/dream) but i don't quite understand this one little thing.
How do you create a "stand alone" compiler. Now, this is a a made up word to describe a compiler that runs as a whole new program. For example 'node index.js'. You dont' have to compile the compiler with something else right.
Where if i create the compiler with say JavaScript, i'd still need to compile the compiler like this for ex 'node compiler.js nameofthefile.ext'.
So then i found that thing called bootstrapping a compiler. So you create a compiler for a your new language with Java or C for example, and then you create a new compiler written in the new language, and compile it with that compiler to get a new compiler written in the new language. But i still don't understand how do run it.
For example if were to make it with C (that is what i am planning to do) then i'd have that file called compiler.c
Now i need to compile the C code so i do for example 'make compiler.c' and that gives me the a compiled version of the c code called just 'compiler'(in Linux that i use) or 'compiler.exe' (in Windows).
So now to run that program i can do ./compiler and than give it for example an argument the/path/to/the/programming_language.someExt
And if all runs well that is going to do what ever the program i wrote in the new language does.
But even now i can't give that version of the compiler to a windows user because the compiler needs to be .exe file.
If you still reading this, there is more...
What if a then want to bootstrap the current compiler.
So now the compiler it self will be called compiler.theExtOfTheProgrammingLang and the code that i want to compiler would be hello_world.theExtOfTheProgrammingLang. But now i can not just run the compiler, because i will need to compile it first using the previous compiler.
That all just made a big mess in my head but i don't want to give up on it.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. While I appreciate your interest, especially that you aren't willing to give up on it, I am afraid that this post may get closed as either "Too broad" or "Unclear what you are asking". Its useful to refer [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section before asking questions. Good luck!

Comment: "Bootstrapping" is needed when you want to write the compiler for your language in the language itself. If that's not your goal, no bootstrapping is necessary. If you write your compiler in C, that's your compiler and you can give it to a friend. (Note that the article you linked uses "compile" in the traditional sense of "translate to a different language", not the post-2000 "translate to a specific machine language".)

Comment: Realisation #1 is that it doesn't matter what language the compiler is written in. Except it will probably be slow if written in a higher level language.

Comment: Got,that. But then if i made a compiler with javascript it would be lets say one file (tho it's not a good practice i know) called compiler.js right.Now if i had a file called helloWorld.someExt and i wanted to compile it, how would i do that. Do i need to compile the javascript comipler with node every time and that is going to compile the new file or am i just dumb and don't get it? :d

Comment: If you write your compiler in JavaScript, you can't get around the need to use an interpreter, like node, to execute it. If you write it in something that can be translated to a native executable, you can make a standalone executable compiler. It works exactly the same as if you had written a program that wasn't a compiler.

Comment: Can you suggest a good tutorial for that ? Tnx

Comment: writing/testing/documenting compilers (normally) takes years and thousands of man hours.   Are you prepared to invest that amount of time and effort?

Comment: Well,i ain't doing a new language that every one is gonna use one day,just wanted to try that my self and see the end result :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to paint you a picture.
You're creating a new language `L`. For that language you wrote a compiler, C<sub>L</sub> in (for instance) Java that compiles from `L` to x86 and creates an ELF executable file (i.e. Linux executable). You need to use the JVM in order to use C<sub>L</sub> (well, technically there are tool-chains that will compile Java to native, but lets ignore that).
Say you don't want to be JVM bound, and instead prefer to run natively on Linux. Well, no problem. You just wrote a compiler that compiles from L to native Linux executable. You just need to use that compiler, C<sub>L</sub>, to write a new compiler C2<sub>L</sub>. C2<sub>L</sub> does the same thing as C<sub>L</sub> only it's written in `L` instead of Java and so you can compile it to native with C<sub>L</sub> (running C<sub>L</sub> on the JVM). Once you've compiled C2<sub>L</sub>, you no longer need the JVM to run or compile anything because C2<sub>L</sub> runs natively and compiles to native executables.

Now, if you want to create another compiler that runs on Windows, you'll need to create a third compiler, C3<sub>L</sub>, that compiles `L` to native EXE (or whatever Windows-compatible format you'll choose) - that compiler will be compiled with C<sub>L</sub> or C2<sub>L</sub>. Once you've compiled C3<sub>L</sub> you can take that executable over to a Windows machine and you're done.

Comment: Great. But i have only one last question. How do you write a program written in java (or any other language) that compiles the new language to a native program. "You're creating a new language L. For that language you wrote a compiler, CL in (for instance) Java that compiles from L to x86 and creates an ELF executable file"

Comment: Also can i do that with JavaScript too. And if yes, can you give me a nice tutorial or smt? tnx!

Comment: What you're asking, "how do you write a program that compiles...", is basically asking how to write a compiler - that a really(!) big question. Basically, that tutorial you're following shows you how to compiler your code to JS, so first thing you'll need is to replace the code generator component with one that compiles to X86

Comment: Here is what i found. I made a different question about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51871293/how-to-give-a-second-argument-to-a-compiled-nectar-program-when-running-it

Answer (score 0):

Look into bison/flex (yacc/lex) and get a book on compilers and formal languages here is a good one [https://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Tools-2nd/dp/0321486811](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811). You might want to start by making a decaf compiler due to its simpler language constructs. Most universities have a decaf compiler project write up that is publicly available. Here is one: https://parasol.tamu.edu/courses/decaf/students/